# How to maintain 2 different versions of an app on the iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, version

Is there any way to maintain 2 different versions of the same app on the iPhone? One version is the actual production build and another version is the development build which I can use for experiments i.e. UI changes

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 4 allows you to create targets for  your applications. You might find those useful. I use them to maintain a free version and a paid version of my apps.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

Each target should then have a different bundle ID as this is what the phone uses to distinguish different apps. If you need a specific ID, (i.e for push notifications, game center or iads), I'm not sure on a solution sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Bundle ID of the development version. You can install different versions of the same app if the bundle IDs are different.